# have multiple table copies in databases for easy join query or do data associate in program?

Tags: database, architecture, large-data, bigdata

In a large system which use multiple databases.

eg:

**db_trade** used for trade information storage

**db_fund** used for user account storage

**db_auth** used for authentication and authorization

In this case **user_info** is common info.

**trade system** and **fund system** UI need display trade or account information with user info. for better performance, it need execute sql query left join **user_info**.

I wan't know how to design in larger system:

Perform data association in program ?
Sync **user_info** table in every databases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are pros and cons to each approach:

The normalized approach stores each piece of data exactly once, and is better from a data integrity perspective. This is the traditional approach used in relational database design. For example, in a banking system you would probably not keep the current account balance in more than one place, right? Because then when you change it in one place, the other one becomes inconsistent, which may lead to wrong business decisions.

The denormalized approach allows to store multiple copies of the same data in different places, and is better for performance. This is the approach generally recommended for big data and NoSQL database design. An example where this makes sense: Suppose you are designing a chat system, and you need to display messages next to the name of the message author. You will probably prefer to store the display name next to the message, and not just the user ID, so that you don't need to do an expensive Join every time you display messages.

If you denormalize, you need to take care of data integrity at the application level. First, you need to make sure that you're clear about what's the source of truth. It's ok to have multiple copies of the user_info ready to be fetched with low latency, but there should be one place where the most correct and up-to-date user info can be found. This is the master table for user info. The other copies of user info should derive from it. So you must decide which one of the databases in your design is the Master of user info.

In the end, you have to make a tradeoff between consistency and performance (which is closely related to availability).
If user_info doesn't change a lot, and you have lots of queries and lots of users, and performance is your main concern - go with the denormalized approach and sync user_info table in every database. Your application will have to keep those tables as consistent as you need, by database-level replication or by some application logic.

If you must have strongly consistent views of the user_info in every query (which is not a typical situation), you may need to sacrifice performance and keep all user info in one location.

Generally, big data systems sacrifice consistency in favor of performance and availability.